# Cannot run two spark shells on a remote machine

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I have Datastax Enterprise 4.6 installed on a cluster - and it's working fine.

Then, a have another instance of dse 4.6 installed on a separate machine (let's call it the "build_node"; it is located in the same data center as the cluster), and I would like to use it to submit jobs to the master on the cluster.

As a starting point, I run a spark shell from the `build_node`, with the remote master (the one on the cluster), and execute a trivial command such as `sc.parallelize(1 to 100).count` - and it's working fine.

With such spark shell *still* open, I execute in another terminal another spark shell: it complains that `Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.` (reasonable), but it seems anyway connected to the remote spark master. However, when I execute the very same trivial command as above, after a while it starts issuing warning messages such as:

`15/01/12 12:37:59 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory`

which, as is, does not make any sense to me given that I have not changed any memory option or such and moreover the very same command succeeded in the first shell. It keeps printing multiple times such message, and after a couple of minutes I killed the process (the one in the first shell returned in a few seconds).

Does anyone can explain what's going on, and possibly suggest how (if possible at all) run multiple spark shells from a machine connected to the same remote master?

Of course any suggestion on how to debug (logs, parameters to set etc) is also of great help.

FYI, I run the shell with the command: `dse spark --master spark://<master ip>:<master port>`

Comment: Could you check in the UI of the first shell (:4040) how many resources it has reserved from the cluster?

Comment: @maasg where exactly I have to watch? I checked the "Executors" tab and there are 5 rows, 4 executors and the driver (fine), and everything is set to 0 in the various cells.

Comment: check Russ's blog. I think this is a resource allocation problem -- www.datastax.com/dev/blog/common-spark-troubleshooting